# Como adicionar títulos acima de input e textarea?

Tags: html, html5, input, textarea

Como adicionar um título acima de *input* e *text-area* e adicionar espaço entre os mesmos?

Ex.:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O título que gostaria de fazer é representado por "Seu texto" e o input por "Texto aqui".

Comment: Cara você vai ter que usar CSS pra fazer isto. Para criar o "titulo" dos inputs você poderia usar uma tag label e manipular ela com css pra ficar do tamanho e com o espaçamento que você quer, os espaços entre os inputs também. Recomendo ler alguns posts e apostilas que ensinam o basico de CSS, é bem fácil de aprender. Da uma lida nisto aqui: http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3557/customizando-formularios-com-css.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Os títulos de `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>` e outros são conhecidos como **label** (*Etiqueta*, em tradução livre para o português).

Podem ser declarados em HTML das seguintes maneiras:

1. Utilizando ***for=" "*** : Referenciamos o `id` do elemento dentro do atributo `for` do elemento *label*:

   ```html
   <label for="name">Nome:</label>
   <input type="text" id="name">
   ```
2. Utilizando ***Elemento*** dentro de ***label*** : Nessa segunda maneira, você não precisa utilizar o `for` e nem mesmo ter um `id` definido para o *input* (ou *select*, *textarea*, etc). Apenas adicionamos o *elemento* dentro do *label*:

   ```html
   <label>Nome:
     <input type="text">
   </label>
   ```

---

**Tips and Tricks**:

1. Além da semântica adicionada ao código, um outro ponto positivo em relação o uso de labels está na melhora da usabilidade. Quando o usuário clicar sobre o texto da *label* o *cursor* automaticamente é colocado dentro do *elemento* pela maioria dos navegadores, o que é muito util para **input type=radio** por exemplo que costumam ter área clicavel pequena.
2. Além da usabilidade visual descrita acima, um outro ponto que também pode ser melhorado é a portabilidade para leitores de tela. Existem as propriedades de **[WAI-ARIA](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Web_applications_and_ARIA_FAQ)** que são bem interessantes nesse ponto e para o caso de labels podemos utilizar o atributo [aria-labelledby](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Usando_o_atributo_aria-labelledby) para referenciar o `id` da *label* ao *elemento*:

   ```html
   <label for="input-name" id="label-name">Name:</label>
   <input labelledby="label-name" id="input-name" type="text">
   ```
3. Um último ponto interessante a destacar está na quebra de linha entre o texto da *label* e o *elemento*. Preferencialmente evite utilizar a tag `<br>`, essa é uma tag utilizada para quebra de texto (*text node*) [segundo documentação do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br). Para fazer essa "quebra" utilizando CSS apenas adicionar **display: block** para o *input*, como no exemplo abaixo:

   ```css
   input {
     display: block;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <label>Nome:
     <input type="text">
   </label>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Quanto ao colocar um título em cima dos `inputs/textareas` você pode usar qualquer tag de texto, mas de preferência `label`, e quanto ao espaçamento abaixo use `margin-bottom` do css.

```css
textarea,
input {
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<label for="txt">Seu Texto</label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<br>
<label for="txt2">Seu Texto</label>
<br>
<textarea id="txt2"></textarea>
```

A regra que coloquei se aplica tanto aos `inputs` quanto aos `textareas`, simplesmente defini uma largura para eles com o `width` e o espaçamento com `margin-bottom`.

Recomendo que você estude um pouco sobre css para a formatação das suas páginas HTML, segue alguns links.

http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-html-css-javascript/introducao-a-html-e-css/

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Aprender/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basico

Existem vários outros sites que ensinam como usar css, basta procurar no nosso querido Google e se divertir.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Lucas, apenas para desencargo, a tag <br> serve para quebra de texto, então não utilize-o para a quebra entre as tags <label> e <input>, nesse caso você pode utilizar display block no input, e o resultado sera o mesmo.